# Ubuntu touch HTML 5 how to create complex headers?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, html5

I am trying to build a small html5 app for Ubuntu touch. In general it is rather difficult to handle the html5 code. The design guide gives a lot of suggestions how to build an app, but neither the documentation nor the tutorials descibe how to implement these elements.

Currently I just want to add a search component to the header as suggested in the design guidelines:
[image]

My header uses a Tab navigation:

```
    <header data-role="header" id="xxx">
  <ul data-role="tabs">
    <li data-role="tabitem" data-page="maintab">Main     </li>
    <li data-role="tabitem" data-page="anotherpage">Favorites</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

My question is how to add a search field to the header, when the header is only defined as a list?